# Django Regrouping items in a table (two dimensional)

Tags: django, django-templates

I've got a problem displaying items in a table, that is both regrouped by columns and rows.
I wrote an app, where employees can log a workday and set a status (office, vacation etc.)

I pass all day items to the template by:

```
results = Tage.objects.filter(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the template I regroup the columns by

```
{% regroup results|dictsort:"employee.id" by employee as employee_entries %}
```

and loop through them

```
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
{% for ma in employee_entries %}
<th>{{ ma.grouper }}</th>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

Thats works fine.
Next thing is regrouping the rows by the day.

```
{% regroup results|dictsort:"employee.id"|dictsortreversed:"starttime" by starttime|date:"d. E Y" as day_entries %}
{% for te in day_entries %}
<tr>
<th colspan="5" style="border-right: 0px;">{{ te.grouper }}</th>
</tr>
```

That also works fine.

Now the tricky part:

I want to display the status of the day an employee has logged by:

```
<tr>
<th>Status</th>
{% for result in te.list %}
<th>{{ result.status }}</th>
{% empty %}
<th></th>
{% endfor %}
</tr>
```

That works fine, if all employees have logged that specific day. If someone hasn't logged a day like others, all status columns are in the wrong place. Of course, that happens because **te.list** is not the same length as the employee list.

Has anyone an approach to such a problem? I googled around a lot, but didn't find a straight-forward solution to such a problem.

Thanks in advance
Conrad

Comment: After trying several things and other people's code, I think is better done in a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to render the table header and body inside the view and pass it to the template and render it with

```
{{ theader|safe }}
```

and so on.

The problem was too complex for the capabilities of Django's template system.